# Responsive site background image code

Tags: background, responsive-design

I have a background which cycles through images, these images have no fixed sizes.

My problem is that I cannot find a simple responsive frame for re-sizing images which are dedicated *background* images. There are plenty of plugins for normal images on websites.

1. The background of my website always has to have the image displayed.
2. cropping is allowed, is allowed the image must re-position itself in the center of the web browser.
3. jQuery or @Media is allowed, I don't really mind.

My images and div look like this:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background:white; position:absolute; margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px;>
    <img src="image1.png">
    <img src="image2.png">
    <img src="image3.png">
</div>
```

A lot of the plugins out there set width to 100% and the height to auto. This will not work as if the browser width is, let's say, 200px and browser height 800px. The image will not cover the entire screen and keep it's aspect ratio. There will be a "gap" under and above the image, so in this case, the height should be 100% and width changed to auto. And of course the other way around if the browser height is 200px and browser length is 800px;

Example of what I want: http://www.martinlogin.se/

Comment: If your HTML looks like that, no wonder it doesn't work. ;-) Maybe put your (repaired) HTML in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I'm missing the "<"'s on purpose, otherwise they won't show up here :/ Everything is working on my site, just when I resize the browser height to 800px and width to 200px the image "shrinks" to a very small size, I would like height to be 100% and width auto (cropping a large portion of the image)

Comment: You don't have to mangle code to display it in your question. Format it properly and use the code button in the toolbar.

Comment: Update: The reason your code wasn't displaying is because it was nested inside your list.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for two different scenarios to be applied depending on screen aspect. This can be done with media queries, but you'll need to settle on some widths and heights.

Start with width-based sizing:

```
#backgroundDiv {width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

When the site is narrower than some point, switch to height-based sizing:

```
#backgroundDiv {width: auto; height: 100%;}
```

You'll need to decide where the transition takes place based on your expected audience's most likely screen size/aspect scenarios, the images you're using, etc.

To have even more flexibility, say for particular aspect ratios instead of widths, you'll need scripting.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been playing with for the last 2 hours :( The images vary in width and height so if I did apply a certain width or height the background will "jump", kinda making it ugly. I want something like this; if(img.width < browser.width) { // then do something }. If you know what I mean. I want a layout like this page: http://www.martinlogin.se/

Comment: So give it a go with jQuery and ask questions when you run into trouble. SO isn't a free freelancer site. ;-)

Comment: Fully aware! I'm very picky and like lightweight code! Been at this for too long, my brain is sizzling haha!